# What caused these crystals to grow on overheated PCB?

Tags: pcb, overheat, screw-terminal

[image: overheated mainboard]

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/3Dprinting/comments/hleo9p/almost_burned_the_house_down_i_think_the_heated)

This is a picture of a screw terminal on a 3d printer mainboard that overheated or caught fire, likely due to a loose connection or overcurrent. One thing that caught my eye is the crystal formation in the heat affected area. What is that? Does it give insight into what caused the damage?

Comment: My guess is that the isolation of the right-side red wire vaporised and (partially) condensed to form the stuff you see.

Comment: Looks like localised leak of .... salt water? cat pee? something corrosive could be the cause of a poor connection which then overheats, rather than vice versa.

Comment: It could possibly be residual solder flux. That stuff tends to crystalize over time, especially in high heat. This is why we specify in our assembly drawings that the boards MUST be cleaned thoroughly following the soldering process. Flux residue is never good to leave on your board unless it's specifically designed to not cause corrosion, and even then it's a good idea to clean it regardless.